# Fatal Error while unwrapping UIImage(data: data) in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uiimage

I have a tableview that is responsible for showcasing a contacts list, however whenever I attempt to load the tableview my project crashes with the error |Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value| 
this is what my code regarding loading the data looks like as of right now

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell",
    for: indexPath) as!TableClass
  let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]
  cell.Name.text = contacts.name
  cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: contacts.image!, scale: 1) //this is the line of code that seems to make my project crash
  return cell
}
```

I've also attempted to use a case method such as this:

```
if case let cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: contacts.image!, scale: 1) {
  print("Hello")
}
```

However when I attempt this the project still crashes and Xcode point to the `if case let` line and reports the same error

Comment: You're force-unwrapping `contacts.image`. What is the value of this? Is it null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Optional Binding to get the optional image.

```
if let image = contacts.image {
    cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: image, scale: 1)
} else {
    //use default placeholder image
}
```